# Best way to constantly check for scheduled events on a website

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

So I am making a website, and something that required for part of the security is having a waiting period when trying to do something, for example trying to delete something, this would help incase someone's account was stolen and someone tried to ruin their account.

I'm already using SQLite so I'm going to create a table in there where scheduled events will be defined.

What I'm wondering is what is the best way to constantly check these scheduled events, it may also be important to note I want to check at least every hour. My immediate thought was creating a separate thread and running a function on there with a while loop in it which will constantly run a chunk of code with a `time.sleep(3600)` at the end of the function, like this:

```
def check_events(self):
    while True:
        # code
        time.sleep(3600)
```

I'm not sure though if this is the most efficient way of doing it.
That function currently is inside my website code class hence the `self`, is that something I need to put on the outside or no?

Comment: Also I currently have this code in my project but instead of `#code` there is `print(True)`, but it prints that twice instead of once, and I can't understand why it does?

Answer (score 0):

I would either create a cron job on your server (which is the most straightforward)

or use a `schedule` module to schedule your task, see example:

```
import time

import schedule
from sharepoint_cleaner import main as cleaner
from sharepoint_uploader import main as uploader
from transfer_statistics import main as transfer_stats

schedule.every(1).hours.do(uploader)
schedule.every(1).hours.do(transfer_stats)
schedule.every().sunday.do(cleaner)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(10)
```

https://github.com/ansys/automatic-installer/blob/4d59573f8623c838aadfd49c312eeaca964c6601/sharepoint/scheduler.py#L3